# Is there a negative zero?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm a very newbie (if not ignorant) to most math-related topics, but ever since I started my primary school, I was always told, that there is no such thing like "*minus zero*" value, because zero is the only value that doesn't have a sign.

Yet, ever since I started using [Amazing Weather HD](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/amazing-weather-hd/9wzdncrfjbrc) application (in Poland, where we currently have winter and with metric system) it keeps telling me, that there is a `-0 Celsius degree` temperature out there.

What am I missing? Is there (in very basic math -- as in this example -- without going to high-university theoretical math) a "*minus zero*" value or does this seem to be a bug in this application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In math:

By definition, $y=-x$ is

> The number $y$ such that $x+y=0$

Which means that, since $0+0=0$, by definition, the number $-0$ is equal to $0$. There's no error in saying $-0$, it's just redundant.

You could say $0$ has no sign, or you could equally say $0$ has *both* signs. It depends on what you define as "sign".

---

In real life:

There's no such thing as *precisely* zero degrees. The exact temperature outside is some number between (presumably) $-30$ and $+50$. It's very unlikely that the number will be precisely $0$, but it can be **close** to $0$.

It is common to use the sign $-0$ to denote that the temperature is near, but **below** zero degrees. If the temperature is $-0.1$, but your display does not show decimal numbers, then the machine would probably display $-0^\circ$.

Comment: A perfect answer, thank you! Waiting for a threshold to accept it. Happy to know, that it wasn't too dumb question! :>

Comment: @trejder It was certainly not a dumb question. It was sort of borderline-about-math (it's as much about programming and engineering), but I think it's a valid question and appropriate for this site.

Comment: I know probably nothing about programming apps, but I would think if it was underflowing below 0 that it would be displayed as just 0. I tried to underflow the Windows Calculator with repeated division of $-1$ by 2 but got tired at -7.3151193042065598861810147091542e-99.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks Actually, if your computer replaces a number that is very close to $0$ with the number $0$, that's not underflow. That's just rounding. An **inderflow** is something that happens if you, for example, have an unsigned integer $0$ and you subtract $1$, resulting in  the positive number $2^{32}-1$. Also, in the app, the number can still be stored as $-0.01434523$, even if it's displayed as $-0$.

Comment: @5xum I'm myself a developer and I ever heard about any programming language, which displays `-0` native, by itself. So, I'm pretty sure, that in above mentioned app it is achieved "by force" by string-combining value of `0` (integer) with `-` character (string). Most likely for the reasons you mentioned -- to denote temperature below zero degrees.

Comment: @trejder Absolutely, I agree. I never said the programming language itself displays $-0$. I just said **the app** does that. Thats exactly why I said that the number is probably still stored as $-0.014324$, and it's only displayed as $-0$.